# What is the justification for $\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} \frac 1 m \sum_{i = 1}^m X_i= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f(x) \, dx = \operatorname EX$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, expectation

I am reading [Explaining the Gibbs Sampler](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2685208?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents). What I have understood so far is that this sampler allows us to generate $X_1, \ldots, X_m$ with density $f(x)$ without actually knowing what $f(x)$ is.

The author says that if we wanted to calculate the mean of $f(x)$ we could use this fact,

$$\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} \frac 1 m \sum_{i=1}^m X_i = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x f(x) \, dx = \operatorname EX.$$

I've never seen the first equality in any text when the topic of expectation of a random variable is introduced.

How exactly is the first equality true?

Comment: I think it follows from law of large number.

Comment: @Ben: I wondered that, but I brushed it off since I didn't an assumption of independence stated. But I may have missed it. I'll read some more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the [Strong Law of Large Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Strong_law), which says that the empirical mean converges to the true mean.

Comment: @AlexR: Doesn't this law require independence?

Comment: @SOULed_Outt: In the paper, each $X_i$ is assumed to be a sample of $f(x)$. If you're instead referring to the *sequence* of generated Gibbs samples $Y^{(i)}$, a similar result will hold based on the Ergodic theorem for markov chains, e.g. $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nY^{(i)}$.

Comment: I am not referring to the Gibbs samples and I fear I don't understand your point about each $X_i$ being a sample of $f(x)$.

Comment: $f(x)$ is a density of a random variable $X$. $X_i$ are independent samples of that random variable. That's my interpretation of the two paragraphs above equation (2.2) of the paper you linked.

Comment: I see. I believe my issue is that I don't see how the $X_i$ are independent. IMO it's not explicitly stated. But, the independence assumption makes things clear, so I'll take it.